# Subscribe to events of a wxWidgets subclass in Python

Tags: event-handling, wxpython

I have a background in C# (.NET2.0) desktop application development and for the last years C for microcontrollers. Now for GUI applications on Linux and Windows, I'm learning python through wxPython. wxGlade created some GUI code and I coded a bit of event handling into it.

I'm on Linux Mint 19 Mate, Python 2.7, wxPython 3.0, wxGlade 0.8.0-1, Stani's Python Editor 0.8.4.

The last version of this program seemed to work from a user standpoint, but mouse events were handled in the frame instead of the panel (see [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689325/how-to-wxpanel-refresh)). Now I got wxGlade to subclass wxPanel and to use the subclass in the frame.

But my attaching handlers to events in the subclass doesn't work. Neither does the panel get painted white on program startup, nor does a mouse click trigger console output.
What's wrong with my **self.Bind()** calls?

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
#
# generated by wxGlade 0.8.0 on Thu Jan  9 14:00:42 2020
#

import wx

# begin wxGlade: dependencies
# end wxGlade

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade



class wxDrawPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: wxDrawPanel.__init__
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        # end wxGlade

        print("binding events...")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.__HandleLEFT_DOWN)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.__HandleLEFT_UP)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.__HandleRIGHT_DOWN)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.__HandleMOTION)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.__HandlePAINT)

        self.LmbDown = False
        self.selectedCoord = None
        self.MainFrame = None

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: wxDrawPanel.__set_properties
        pass
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: wxDrawPanel.__do_layout
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def __HandleLEFT_DOWN(self, event):
        self.LmbDown = True
        coord = event.GetPosition()
        print("HandleLEFT_DOWN at ", coord)
        self.selectedCoord = self.MainFrame.FindNearestInVincinity(self.MainFrame.coords, coord, 5)
        if(None == self.selectedCoord):
            self.MainFrame.coords.append(coord)
        else:
            self.MainFrame.coords.remove(self.selectedCoord)
        self.Refresh()
        event.Skip()

    def __HandleLEFT_UP(self, event):
        self.LmbDown = False
        coord = event.GetPosition()
        print("HandleLEFT_UP at ", coord)
        if(None != self.selectedCoord):
            self.MainFrame.coords.append(self.selectedCoord)
            self.selectedCoord = None
            self.Refresh()
        event.Skip()

    def __HandleRIGHT_DOWN(self, event):
        coord = event.GetPosition()
        print("HandleRIGHT_DOWN at ", coord)
        nearestCoord = self.MainFrame.FindNearestInVincinity(self.MainFrame.coords, coord, 5)
        if(None != nearestCoord):
            self.MainFrame.coords.remove(nearestCoord)
            self.Refresh()
        event.Skip()

    def __HandleMOTION(self, event):
        if(None != self.selectedCoord):
            self.selectedCoord = event.GetPosition()
            self.Refresh()
        event.Skip()

    def __HandlePAINT(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        brush = wx.Brush("white")
        dc.SetBackground(brush)
        dc.Clear()

        pen = wx.Pen("red")
        dc.SetPen(pen)
        for coord in self.MainFrame.coords:
            dc.DrawLine(coord[0] - 2, coord[1] - 2, coord[0] + 2, coord[1] + 2)
            dc.DrawLine(coord[0] - 2, coord[1] + 2, coord[0] + 2, coord[1] - 2)

        if(None != self.selectedCoord):
            shadowPen = wx.Pen("gray")
            dc.SetPen(shadowPen)
            dc.DrawLine(self.selectedCoord[0], self.selectedCoord[1] - 1, self.selectedCoord[0] + 4, self.selectedCoord[1] + 3)
            dc.DrawLine(self.selectedCoord[0], self.selectedCoord[1] + 3, self.selectedCoord[0] + 4, self.selectedCoord[1] - 1)
            dc.SetPen(pen)
            dc.DrawLine(self.selectedCoord[0] - 2, self.selectedCoord[1] - 2, self.selectedCoord[0] + 2, self.selectedCoord[1] + 2)
            dc.DrawLine(self.selectedCoord[0] - 2, self.selectedCoord[1] + 2, self.selectedCoord[0] + 2, self.selectedCoord[1] - 2)

        event.Skip()

# end of class wxDrawPanel
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__init__
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((729, 521))

        # Menu Bar
        self.MainMenuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        wxglade_tmp_menu = wx.Menu()
        wxglade_tmp_menu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Open", "")
        wxglade_tmp_menu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Close", "")
        wxglade_tmp_menu.AppendSeparator()
        wxglade_tmp_menu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Exit", "")
        self.MainMenuBar.Append(wxglade_tmp_menu, "File")
        wxglade_tmp_menu = wx.Menu()
        wxglade_tmp_menu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Preferences", "")
        self.MainMenuBar.Append(wxglade_tmp_menu, "Edit")
        wxglade_tmp_menu = wx.Menu()
        wxglade_tmp_menu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "About", "")
        self.MainMenuBar.Append(wxglade_tmp_menu, "?")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.MainMenuBar)
        # Menu Bar end
        self.DrawPanel = wxDrawPanel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        # end wxGlade

        self.coords = []
        self.DrawPanel.MainFrame = self

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("frame")
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__do_layout
        MainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        Statusbar = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        MainSizer.Add(self.DrawPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        Statusbar.Add((0, 0), 0, 0, 0)
        Statusbar.Add((0, 0), 0, 0, 0)
        Statusbar.Add((0, 0), 0, 0, 0)
        Statusbar.Add((0, 0), 0, 0, 0)
        MainSizer.Add(Statusbar, 0, 0, 0)
        self.SetSizer(MainSizer)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def FindNearestInVincinity(self, coords, coord, maxDistance):
        if(coord in coords):
            return(coord)

        for d in range(1, maxDistance):
            for i in range(-maxDistance, maxDistance):
                oneCoord = (coord[0] + i, coord[1] - d)
                if(oneCoord in self.coords):
                    return(oneCoord)

                oneCoord = (coord[0] + d, coord[1] + i)
                if(oneCoord in self.coords):
                    return(oneCoord)

                oneCoord = (coord[0] - i, coord[1] + d)
                if(oneCoord in self.coords):
                    return(oneCoord)

                oneCoord = (coord[0] - d, coord[1] - i)
                if(oneCoord in self.coords):
                    return(oneCoord)

        return(None)

# end of class MyFrame

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.MainFrame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.MainFrame)
        self.MainFrame.Show()
        return True

# end of class MyApp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: As with yesterday's question `MainSizer.Add(self.DrawPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)` set the `proportion` flag when adding to the sizer.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Yes, thank you. I was fully under the impression that the design part was working. But as it seems now, I had never seen the panel at all. That was all custom painted frame at the exact location of where the panel should have been.

Comment: I have found that when debugging, it can be useful to give things a background colour. This ensures that you know a) it's there and b) where it is.